# Insert property into object at specific index in Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

This question has been asked more then once, but I can't seem to find the right solution anywhere. It's probably because the right way is to create it as ordered array instead of object. But I am in a position where I must use an object, and later by iterating with `for...in` loop over that object, fields are being created on a dialog in the same order they are listed in an object.
My object looks like this:

```
fields: {
   category_id: {label: 'Category', type: 'text'}, 
   title: {label: 'Title', type: 'text'}, 
   description: {label: 'Desc', type: 'textarea'}
}
```

Now, from server there can be returned multiple titles and when that happens I need to insert them all below `title`:

```
fields: {
   category_id: {label: 'Category', type: 'text'}, 
   title: {label: 'Title', type: 'text'}, 
   title_1: {label: 'Title', type: 'text'}, 
   title_2: {label: 'Title', type: 'text'}, 
   description: {label: 'Desc', type: 'textarea'}
}
```

I found this [function](https://gomakethings.com/how-to-add-a-new-item-to-an-object-at-a-specific-position-with-vanilla-js/), which adds property at specific index, but you need to hard-code that index and sometimes I don't know which what is the order number of that index (I need to set it dynamically).

Is there a function which would let me to specify name of property after which I want to add new properties into object or even better to replace specific property with multiple new ones (for example swap `title` with `title, title_1 and title_2`)?

Comment: The properties in an object don't have an order (not quite right anymore, but you should definitely not rely on it).

Comment: I know that, but the code itself is written this way and it's too late to rewrite it, creating arrays out of those objects. It's not my code, it's code of a company I am working for, so I just need to adapt to it now.
It works like this now, if category comes first and title comes second, I am gonna have fields on a dialog created that way. If I swap their positions inside `fields` object, positions on dialog are going to be swapped also. The `for...in` loop is responsibe for that

Comment: You can't, because there's no order... Really... If you need a specific order, then store it in an array and iterate over this array instead of the object to access the properties in the required order

Comment: Object properties in an object __don't have any specific storing order__, iteration methods are arranging the properties in a specific order during iteration.

Comment: how about changing the value of `title` into an array which can keep specific order and you can also iterate it?

Comment: There are multiple other solutions to handle this and each one of them is better then the one I am looking for. We are using VueJS here, and the data which is sent from here is later being iterated with v-for and it's creating fiedls on dialog. But my boss was like "please don't change the logic in template, just add new properties into object". But by adding properties, they are automatically being added to end of that object and later displayed in the bottom of dialog window which doesn't work for me. Thanks for help, I will delete this question as it's not the logic someone should follow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd discourage you to rely on any order of object props except the order of inserion (which I discourage you as well)
But sure, to persist your order you can just build your object into array, then insert props, then build object back

```
const fields = {
   category_id: {label: 'Category', type: 'text'}, 
   title: {label: 'Title', type: 'text'}, 
   description: {label: 'Desc', type: 'textarea'}
}
const fieldsArray = Object.entries(fields)
const index = fieldsArray.findIndex(([key]) => key === 'title')
const reconstructedFields = Object.fromEntries([
    ...fieldsArray.slice(0, index), // fields prior
    fieldsArray[index], // field you want to insert fiedls after
    ...[['title_1', {label: 'Title', type: 'text'}],['title_1', {label: 'Title', type: 'text'}]], // the fields to insert
    ...fieldsArray.slice(index+1)]) // fields after
```

Comment: Right, this actually could help. Gonna try it right now, and will be back to report if it succeeded

Comment: @nikname You never got back! What happend? Did it work?

Comment: @riper Honestly, I can't remember what this question was about, I moved from company in which I've been working on project where I needed this.
But from this perspective, I would say this answer is totally acceptable and that it does exactly what I needed at that moment